# Kafka Connect FileConfigProvdier not working

Tags: db2, apache-kafka-connect

I'm running Kafka Connect with JDBC Source Connector for DB2 in standalone mode. Everything works fine, but I'm putting the passwords and other sensitive info into my connector file in plain text. I'd like to remove this, so I found that FileConfigProvider can be used:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#fileconfigprovider

However, when I try to use this it does not seem to pick up my properties file. Here's what I'm doing:

`connect.standalone.oroperties` -

```
config.providers=file
config.providers.file.class=org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
```

`secrets.properties` -

```
password=thePassword
```

`Source Config` -

```
 "connection.password": "${file:/Users/me/app/context/src/main/kafkaconnect/connector/secrets.properties:password}",
  "table.whitelist": "MY_TABLE",
  "mode": "timestamp",
```

When I try to load my source connector (via rest api) I get the following error:

> {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.26.14] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:db2://11.1.111.111:50000/mydb\nInvalid value com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.26.14] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:db2://11.1.111.111:50000/mydb\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}

The password I'm providing is correct. It works if I just hardcode it into my source json. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: As a note, I get similar results on the sink side inserting into a Postgres database.

Edit: Result of GET /connectors:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_source_test-dev",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "timestamp.column.name": "UPDATED_TS",
        "connection.password": "${file:/opt/connect-secrets.properties:dev-password}",
        "validate.non.null": "false",
        "table.whitelist": "MY_TABLE",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "topic.prefix": "db2-test-",
        "transforms.extractInt.field": "kafka_id",
        "_comment": "The Kafka topic will be made up of this prefix, plus the table name  ",
        "connection.user": "username",
        "name": "jdbc_source_test-dev",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:db2://11.1.111.111:50000/mydb",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "connector": "jdbc_source_test-dev",
            "task": 0
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

Comment: Please check properties filename - is it really `connect.standalone.oroperties`?

Comment: That was my mistake, it's not. It's connect-standalone.properties. The same file I have my plugin path in, so I know that works

Comment: I have now even tried in my cloud environment with connect-distributed.properties and it still doesn't work. I know it's at least trying to read from the file though because if I have my file path to an incorrect one in the json file like something like ${file:/Users/me/app/context/src/main/kafkaconnect/connector/secretsx.properties:password} (notice the x after secrets), I get an error saying it cannot read from secretsx.properties

Comment: Also check file permissions

Comment: So changing file perms in distributed cluster at least allowed the load of the source connector to work. So now it returns in GET /connectors. However, if I look at the connector status with GET connectors/{name}/status I see a similar error: Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.26.14] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid.

Comment: Please provide output of `GET connectors/{name}/config`

Comment: Added it in my original post. Note that after some amount of restarting kafka-connect on my cluster I was able to finally make it go through for the source. Then I had similar issues with the sink but again after restarts, etc I was able to get it to load. Then, once I made an update in the source that should be synced to the sink, I would get the same db password error again. I removed all connectors, all topics, and restarted kafka connect again, now I'm back to the original state where I can't even create the source because of the password error

Comment: Looking through the logs, I do see this on startup of kafka-connect: DistributedConfig values:
access.control.allow.methods =
access.control.allow.origin =
bootstrap.servers = [kafka01:9092, kafka02:9092, ka
client.id =
config.providers = []

Notice config.providers is empty

Comment: How many nodes in cluster do you have?